# CPU at 99-100% after installing Ubuntu

Tags: cpu, acpi, ahci

Yesterday I went to install ubuntu, but the screen would freeze during loading so I never really got to the installation screen. So I turned off the acpi as written in the link below and it worked.
[Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB drive freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861743/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-from-a-usb-drive-freezes)

The next problem was that on the installation screen, before even getting to install it it said that my disc has only 8GB of memory and it needs 8.4GB, which is impossible since it was a half-empty SSD of 250GB. Coming from windows 10, the answer in the following link worked. [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS unrecognized hard drive -- not enough disk space to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764353/ubuntu-16-04-lts-unrecognized-hard-drive-not-enough-disk-space-to-install)

Now the problem is, I think not very long after turning ubuntu on today, it started to be reeeaaally slow and choppy, at times even freeze for prolonged periods of time like Windows back in the days, and I would have to manually turn off the laptop. I updated the graphic drivers, it didn't help.

It turns out the CPU is constantly at 99-100% even with no running processes and that it only recognizes 1 CPU out of 4, confirmed by running the commands from the following answer.
[How to find the number of CPU cores including virtual?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724228/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-including-virtual)

nproc;
lscpu;
cat /proc/cpuinfo;

I have no idea what to do, I would really need some help.

Medion Erazer P6705;
Intel Core i5-8300H QuadCore Processor 2,30 - 4,00GHz;
8GB DDR4;
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050Ti, 4GB VRAM

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Even with 1 core CPU utilization should only be about 10% when idle. You sure have had your fair share of problems and I hope someone else with a Coffee Lake processor comes along with solution. Because it's a newer processor I would try manually installing a newer kernel (I'm using 4.14.114 which should also work for you): https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I'd get rid of the `acpi=off` option, and install the recommended Nvidia driver. If the screen goes black, you could try `nomodeset`.