# why the number of cores is different than expected?

Tags: multi-core, system-info

I am trying [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/724236/1047017) solution to a similar answer , in order to determine how many cores my systems have

so I try the following commands

1)

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
```

2. 

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id'
```

3. lscpu
4. nproc

My host ubuntu PC gives to all of these the number 12

However when I apply the same for my Jetson AGX Xavier I got

1. 4
2. nothing
3. 8
4. 4

However the specs says that this is a CPU

```
8-core ARM v8.2 64-bit CPU, 8MB L2 + 4MB L3
```

When I apply above to a DRIVE AGX Xavier (with CPU 8-core “Carmel” CPUs based on ARM v8 ISA)

I get

1. 6
2. nothing
3. 6
4. 4

so Why all the different info and which command do really gives me the number of cores I can use?

Comment: ARM is a very different beast.

Comment: @ChanganAuto so how do I get the available cores for an ARM environment?

Comment: you grep for processor and then count the lines, if those lines say: "no processor information known" you count 1. The second is to consider that a core is an architect dependent thing. is hyperthreading 2 cores or one. if it's an 8 Core ARM, is it a big.little? ... nproc shows how many cores are available, not how many there are. virtualization makes some cores available and you can have loads of virtual cores that share one physical core... best just to look at the specs and draw your conclusions from there
https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/nvidia/microarchitectures/carmel